# Extract value of xml tags containing a particular string

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, string-parsing, stax

I have a xml file containing all different types of protocols in the tag "PROTOCOLTAG". I want to extract the values of only those tags which contain the string "SITELINK". Currently I'm able to get the values of all the tag "PROTOCOLTAG". Please help

The xml file..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CDMDataXML xmlns="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema CDMLoaderXMLSchema.xsd">
  <NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004236">
    <NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.SNMPV1-SSL</NAME>
    <PROTOCOLTAG>SNMPV1:SSL</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004237">
    <NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.SNMPV2-SSL</NAME>
    <PROTOCOLTAG>SNMPV2:SSL</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004238">
    <NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.BACNET-SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER-RS-485</NAME>
    <PROTOCOLTAG>BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER/RS-485</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004239">
    <NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.BACNET-SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED-RS-485</NAME>
    <PROTOCOLTAG>BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED/RS-485</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
```

Java code..

```
    XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader rdr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("test.xml"));
while (rdr.hasNext()) {
    if (rdr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("PROTOCOLTAG")) {
          System.out.println(rdr.getElementText());
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
 BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER/RS-485
 BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED/RS-485
```

Current Output..

```
 SNMPV1:SSL
 SNMPV2:SSL
 BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER/RS-485
 BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED/RS-485
```

Comment: Current Output: Nothing, because your code doesn't print anything?

Comment: I have made the changes. Forgot the println statement..

Comment: So you already have the XML parsing part done, you just need to know how to check if a string contains a particular sub-string inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader rdr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\pramod.karandikar\\Desktop\\Test.xml"));
while (rdr.hasNext()) {
      if (rdr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
          if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("PROTOCOLTAG")) {
               String txt = rdr.getElementText();
               if (txt.indexOf("SITELINK") > 0) {
                  System.out.println(txt);
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Or `txt.contains("SITELINK")`. Also, your code will not print lines that start with SITELINK.

Comment: Yes, either of `indexOf` and `contains` could be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is for contains() method;

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader rdr;
try {
   rdr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader( "test.xml"));
      while (rdr.hasNext()) {
        if (rdr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
          if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("PROTOCOLTAG")) {
               String str = rdr.getElementText().toString();
               if (str.toString().contains("SITELINK")) {
                 System.out.println(str);
               }
           }
      }
   }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XMLStreamException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}